# Missing cyclic permutations of numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have numpy arrays containing 2 floats each :

```
Unit_1 = [40000.0, 47000.0]
Unit_2 = [12000.0, 14000.0]
Unit_3 = [16000.0, 18000.0]
```

I want to build a permutation for the combination of units based upon their values, like:

```
[(40000, 12000, 16000), (40000, 12000, 18000), (40000, 14000, 160000), (40000, 14000, 18000).........]
```

getting all the possible permutations.

I'm using the following:

```
list(list(zip(r, p, q)) for (r, p,q) in zip(repeat(Unit_1), permutations(Unit_2), permutations(Unit_3)))
```

the output it gives is:

```
[[(40000.0, 12000.0, 16000.0), (47000.0, 14000.0, 18000.0)], [(40000.0, 14000.0, 18000.0), (47000.0, 12000.0, 16000.0)]]
```

How can I get the remaining permutations ?

Comment: how many `unit`s do you have?  And do they always have 2 elements each?

Comment: Units can be 'n' but they always have 2 elements each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to need the permutations, but the *Cartesian product* of the 3 lists. Use `itertools.product`.

```
items = list(itertools.product(Unit_1, Unit_2, Unit_3))
```

To generate permutations, you need the permutations of *each item* from the above collection. So, something like

```
perms = sum((list(permutations(item)) for item in items), [])
```

Comment: I tried list(product([Unit_1,Unit_2,Unit_3],repeat = 3)) but its not combining the third !

Comment: Is it possible to reshuffle the order of the units too like instead of just (Unit_1,Unit_2,Unit_3), the output can to permutation like (Unit_2,Unit_3,Unit_1) and so on ?

Comment: @Sultan: in that case you would need to get the permutations of each item of the product. `itertools` also has permutations

Comment: I tried using _list(it.permutations(it.product(Data1,Data2,Data3),r=1))_ but the output is the same as list(itertools.product(Unit_1, Unit_2, Unit_3))